# Resharper for VS 2019 Templates explorer

Tags: resharper

`Resharper 2019`

In the below screenshot you can see that I have a "`Test Fixture`" Template in the C# `Quicklist`.

However, when I go to choose a template to insert, that doesn't appear in the list.

How can I get the `Resharper Templates` to appear in the `Template list`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the "Text Fixture" file template and look at the "Availablity" field, you will find "C# projects, References nunit.framework". Well, it means you need "NUnit" as a reference for a project. Or you can update this field to keep only "C# projects".